# Given limit f(x) = L at x=c , does the function f(x) "always" need to be defined in the close neighborhood of c?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, epsilon-delta

According to the epsilon-delta definition of a limit,
L is limit of f(x) at c if
For every arbitrary ε>0 we can find δ>0 such that
for "all" x satisfying c-δ<x<c+δ (except c possibly), f(x) lies in (L-ε,L+ε)

does this definition imply that f(x) has to be defined at "all" points in the interval
(c-δ,c+δ)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Any function $f:A\to B$ of course has to be defined on all of $A$, otherwise it is not a function. However, you may defined $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and still pick $c=0$ and, say, $\delta = 2$. This does not mean that $f$ must be defined on the interval $(-2,0)$, however: The definition says more precisely that for $x\in A$ satisfying $c-\delta<x<c+\delta$, $f(x)$ has to be $\epsilon$-close to $f(c)$. With the quantifier $x\in A$, we do not run into any problems.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification! I had the same feeling but the that quantifier isn't explicitly mentioned in the book I'm reading, and hence the confusion.

Comment: Ah, that seems troubling. For your reference, here is the very technical definition of limit: For $f:A\to B$, $L\in B$ is the limit of $f$ at $c\in A$ if
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta >0\forall x\in A: |x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: For the limit to exist, it's also required that $c$ is an accumulation point of $A$, meaning that for every $\delta>0$ there exists some $x \in A$ such that $0 < |x-c| < \delta$.